# easybill REST API POST over PHP

Tags: php, json, rest

this is my first post here. I hope that I get my question right.
I use the google translator from German to English because my English is not that good.

I would like to use the "api" from easybill. GET worked. But unfortunately I can't do it with the POST.

I hope someone can help me.

I would like to create a new customer for testing. My goal is to generate invoices later using PHP.
The "api" for easybill can be found here: https://www.easybill.de/api/

I tried the following code but unfortunately I can't find the error.

```
$url = "https://api.easybill.de/rest/v1/customers";
$data =  array(
    
          'first_name'   => 'Foo',
          'last_name'    => 'Bar',
          'company_name' => 'FooBar GmbH',
          'emails'       => array ('foo.bar@foobar.com'
            )


);

$postdata = json_encode(array($data));
$accesstoken = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headr[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$accesstoken;

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headr);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r ($result);
```

Best regards from Germany.

Comment: What is your exact error when you try to POST ?

Comment: 400 Bad Request
nginx

Comment: Content-length: 0 for sure isn't right.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm a little step further. :-) I commented out the line. Now comes the error message: {"code":20000,"message":"Bitte f\u00fcllen Sie alle Felder aus.","arguments":["last_name","company_name"]} But the data is filled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistakes:

1. `Content-length: 0`  doesn't make any sense and is utterly wrong here. Afaik you can remove it completely since curl does this for you.
2. `$postdata = json_encode(array($data));` will wrap your array in another array, which isn't correct here. It yields in:

   [{"first_name":"Foo","last_name":"Bar","company_name":"FooBar GmbH","emails":["foo.bar@foobar.com"]}]

where it has to be:

```
{"first_name":"Foo","last_name":"Bar","company_name":"FooBar GmbH","emails":["foo.bar@foobar.com"]}
```

just remove the array call:

```
$postdata = json_encode($data);
```